# make a UIButton imageView Bigger than the frame and then back to its original size?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to make the `UIButton` image transform from its current size to twice its size and then back to its original size similar to the facebook "like" animation.

I'm using this code but for some reason it is doing the reverse action; i.e. first shrinks and only then getting large again.

What am I doing wrong? It works perfectly on a `uiimageView` but not on a `uibutton`

```
[self.likeButton setClipsToBounds:NO];
CGAffineTransform firstTransform = self.likeButton.imageView.transform;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.15f animations:^{

    self.likeButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(firstTransform, 2, 2);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.15f animations:^{

        self.likeButton.imageView.transform = firstTransform;
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I solved it by adding a uiimageview above the button and animate it instead of the button image.

its a hack but its working.

Comment: Actually its nota hack - what you are trying to do is a hack. The system provides widgets that are mostly opaque (meaning, their interworkings are not public) - common to virtually everything apple supplies. Once you start trying to make one of these widgets do something it has no public interface to do, then you are on thin ice so to speak, and the common response is to then design your own widget, of course more work. So I would not label it as a hack, its as valid a solution as any you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Layers have a property `masksToBounds` and UIView has `clipsToBounds`. Most likely the button has these set to YES on the primary view or subviews. Its possible you can discover which ones have these set to YES, and set them temporarily to NO.

Answer (score 0):

//set button.masktobound=NO

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.15f animations:^{

 self.likeButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,2.0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

[UIView animateWithDuration:.15f animations:^{

    self.likeButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
}];
}];
```

//Try this